# Substituting the second occurrence of a word/phrase in ed

Tags: ed

What would the syntax be for replacing only the second/third occurrence of a word/phrase in ed?

```
He wanted to buy groceries from the shop, but preferred not having to go into the shop. >>
He wanted to buy groceries from the shop, but preferred not having to go into it. >>
```

Comment: Why not use `sed`?

Comment: @HatLess `ed` is an interactive editor, while `sed` is a non-interactive stream editor based on `ed`. If one is editing a document in `ed`, it makes little sense to employ `sed` for specific actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution command in `ed`, `s///`, takes zero or more flags at the end of the command string. If the flags include a positive integer *n*, the substitution will act on the *n*:th match.

Assuming you want to replace the second occurrence of substring `the shop` on the current line with the string `it`, you would therefore use

```
s/the shop/it/2
```

A snapshot from an editing session could look like the following, where the user looks at the current line with `p` and then decides to make the change to the second occurrence of `the shop`, displaying the line again after the edit (using the `p` *flag* of the `s///` command):

```
p
He wanted to buy groceries from the shop, but preferred not having to go into the shop.
s/the shop/it/2p
He wanted to buy groceries from the shop, but preferred not having to go into it.
```

This feature of the `s///` editing command was inherited by `sed`.